# How to compare records in same SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

My requirement is to compare each column of row with its previous row.

1. Compare row 2 with row 1
2. Compare row 3 with row 2

Also, if there is no difference, I need to make that column NULL. Eg: request_status_id of row 3 is same as that of row 2 so I need to update request_status_id of row 3 to NULL.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: @philipxy I need to compare update the table. There will be 100s of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement that employs `LAG` window function available from SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
UPDATE #mytable
SET request_status_id = NULL
FROM #mytable AS m
INNER JOIN  (
   SELECT payment_history_id, request_status_id, 
   LAG(request_status_id) OVER(ORDER BY payment_history_id) AS prevRequest_status_id
   FROM #mytable ) t
ON  m.payment_history_id = t.payment_history_id
WHERE t.request_status_id = t.prevRequest_status_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6715e/1)

**EDIT:**

It seems the requirement of the OP is to `SET` *every* column of the table 
to `NULL`, in case the previous value is same as the current value. In this case the query becomes a bit more verbose. Here is an example with two columns being set. It can easily be expanded to incorporate any other column of the table:

```
UPDATE #mytable
SET request_status_id = CASE WHEN t.request_status_id = t.prevRequest_status_id THEN NULL
                             ELSE T.request_status_id
                        END,
    request_entity_id = CASE WHEN t.request_entity_id = t.prevRequest_entity_id THEN NULL
                             ELSE t.request_entity_id
                        END
FROM #mytable AS m
INNER JOIN  (
   SELECT payment_history_id, request_status_id, request_entity_id,
   LAG(request_status_id) OVER(ORDER BY payment_history_id) AS prevRequest_status_id,
   LAG(request_entity_id) OVER(ORDER BY payment_history_id) AS prevRequest_entity_id
   FROM #mytable ) t
ON  m.payment_history_id = t.payment_history_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b5f9/1)

Comment: I need to do this for all columns in the table not just for 'request_status_id' column . Is that possible in single statement ?

Comment: @VinayakPrabha You need to update all columns ? In OP you are only talking about `request_status_id`.

Comment: Yes. "request_status_id" was just an example which I mentioned. Also, there are many more columns other than the ones shown in screenshot. Need to do the same for those as well.

Comment: @VinayakPrabha Or do you need just to *compare* all other column as well and, if *all* match with previous value *then* update just `request_status_id` ?

Comment: No. Can you please look into my previous comment? I just updated it.

Comment: @VinayakPrabha Let me get this straight. If `request_status_id` is same as previous `request_status_id` then set it to `NULL`. If `description` is same as previous `description` then set it to `NULL`, right?

Comment: Correct. There are many more columns other than the ones shown in screenshot. Need to do the same for those as well

Comment: @VinayakPrabha Have a look at the edit I made. I think it matches your requirement now.